# What is the difference between (local) and (pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

What is the difference between `(local)` and `(pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS` server names?

When I create database in `(local)` server will it be different than when created on `(pc-name-)\SQLEXPRESS`??

Can you please help me to get the exact difference between these databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the server on a machine named "XXX" then on that machine only you can (for convenience) use `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as an address as the server is local to that machine.

On any other machine (including XXX itself) you can use `XXX\SQLEXPRESS` to indicate the server is running on XXX, and that is what should be connected to.

Comment: but i see the difference on my PC itself the db/table created on (local) server not be available on (pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS and viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

When you refer to (local) you mean SQL Server unnamed instance of local (localhost) server. Then name (pc-name)\SQLEXPRESS refers to named SQL Server instance located on given computer. Those are separate server instances.